# Function expression, returning callback function

Tags: javascript

After looking at and experimenting with this code I have been unable to figure out what is going on and how I can use the information that is returned.

Where is "return callback(err, res, body)" returning to?

edit: 
I want to return the data stored in 'body' but its scope is only in that function thats in the call to 'request'. How do I get the data 'body' to return all the way out when i call 'makerequest' so i can use the 'body' data. I hope I am making sense

```
var makerequest = function(set_parameters, callback) {

         ....

 request(URL, function(err, res, body){
    return callback(err, res, body);
 });
};
```

Comment: We don't really know what `request` is doing with the result, but usually `return`ing in an asynchronous callback is futile and should not be done.

Comment: You just should do  `request(URL, callback);`

Comment: "*How do I get the data 'body' to return all the way out to where i call 'makerequest'*" - that's impossible. It's asynchronous.

Comment: thanks for the replies, still learning.

Answer (score 0):

You access the JSON in the callback function:

```
makerequest(set_parameters, function(err, res, body){
      //do stuff with the body here
})
```

Comment: How do I make it so I can get 'body' to return from that inner funtion ie: var temp = makerequest(..) and that gives me back 'body' and stores it as temp.

Comment: That's not possible with javascript's asynchronicity